# I don't know how to exactly compute this determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, determinant

I've tried to compute this determinant by row transformations and column transformations, but it gives me a formula that doesn't work. The determinant is:

\begin{vmatrix}
x & a & b & c & d\\
a & x & b & c & d\\
a & b & x & c & d\\
a & b & c & x & d\\
a & b & c & d & x
\end{vmatrix}

I thought I could start doing row 5 - row 4, row 4 - row 3, row 3 - row 2 and row 2 - row 1 and then you get this determinant:

\begin{vmatrix}
x & a & b & c & d\\
a-x & x-a & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & b-x & x-b & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & c-x & x-c & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & d-x & x-d
\end{vmatrix}

Then I made column 1 - column 2, column 2 - column 3, column 3 - column 4, column 4 - column 5 and you get:

\begin{vmatrix}
x-a & a-b & b-c & c-d & d\\
0 & x-a & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & x-b & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & x-c & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x-d
\end{vmatrix}

And, as it is triangular, you can multiply the diagonal elements, so you get that the determinant is:

$(x-a)^2(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$

But this isn't correct and I don't know what to do, could someone please help me? I'd really appreciate.

Comment: After your row operations , the column operation C1-C2 does not yied the matrix you got. For example the element $0$ of 3rd row and 1st column would become $0 -(b-x)=x-b$ and not stay $0$

Comment: Oh, I see that now, thanks a lot, I didn't notice that.

Comment: It's best to just expand it at that step. And then work with 4×4 minors that you will end up with

Comment: Is it $(x+a+b+c+d)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed I should have started with column 4 - column 5 instead of column 1 - column 2, and I get the same as you, Pythagoras. Thanks

Comment: Hint: Let $C_k$ be the $k^{th}$ column of given matrix, we have $C_1+\cdots + C_5 = (x+a+b+c+d)u$ where $u$ is a column vector with all entries $1$.

Answer (score 8):

Notice that the sum of every row equals to $(a+b+c+d+x).$ You can take this approach:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
x & a & b & c & d\\
a & x & b & c & d\\
a & b & x & c & d\\
a & b & c & x & d\\
a & b & c & d & x
\end{vmatrix} \xrightarrow{\text{$C_1=C_1+C_2+C_3+C_4+C_5$}}  $$

$$ 
\begin{vmatrix}
(a+b+c+d+x) & a & b & c & d\\
(a+b+c+d+x) & x & b & c & d\\
(a+b+c+d+x) & b & x & c & d\\
(a+b+c+d+x) & b & c & x & d\\
(a+b+c+d+x) & b & c & d & x
\end{vmatrix} $$ $$= (a+b+c+d+x) \begin{vmatrix}
1 & a & b & c & d\\
1 & x & b & c & d\\
1 & b & x & c & d\\
1 & b & c & x & d\\
1 & b & c & d & x
\end{vmatrix}$$
Now, we can substract the first row from all of the other rows:
$$= (a+b+c+d+x) \begin{vmatrix}
1 & a & b & c & d\\
0 & x-a & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & b-a & x-b & 0 & 0\\
0 & b-a & c-b & x-c & 0\\
0 & b-a & c-b & d-c & x-d
\end{vmatrix} \xrightarrow{\text{Expand $C_1$}} $$

$$(a+b+c+d+x) \begin{vmatrix}
x-a & 0 & 0 & 0\\
b-a & x-b & 0 & 0\\
b-a & c-b & x-c & 0\\
b-a & c-b & d-c & x-d
\end{vmatrix} = $$ $$=(a+b+c+d+x)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$$

Answer (score 5):

Another approach: Consider it as a polynomial in $x$. Note that it will vanish when $x$ is any of $a,b,c,d$, since then we see a repeated row. It will also vanish when $x = -a-b-c-d$, since then all rows sum to $0$, and so we have the eigenvalue $0$ with eigenvector $(1,1,1,1,1)$.  Furthermore, we know that the leading coefficient is $1$.  Therefore the determinant is

$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-(-a -b-c-d)).$$